# What are the specs of MDM endpoints in Azure AD?

Tags: azure, mdm

> To support Azure AD enrollment, MDM vendors must host and expose a
>   Terms of Use endpoint and an MDM enrollment endpoint (quote from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/azure-active-directory-integration-with-mdm))

But I can't find the specification of what MDM endpoints should look like. What exactly should vendor expose?

I know that my question is unfortunately not valid for SO because I'm asking for information/experience more then some particular code problem. It's more of a developer question then administration question.
Please, does anyone know what are the specs for MDM integration? We want to fork our product (which includes MDM component) to create Azure-based version but after more than a few hours of googling/binging I still can't find any specific information about MDM integration. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In Azure, we can add MDM application via Azure Portal, like this:

[image]

And the default `MDM terms of use URL` and `MDM discovery URL` like this:

[image]

Sorry, I am not good at coding, but I think we can refer to this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/MobileDeviceManagementProtocolRef/3-MDM_Protocol/MDM_Protocol.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017387-CH3-SW2) to find the specification of what MDM endpoints.

Comment: Yeap, I know how to add MDM. Unfortunately I'm interested in how to "create" one, not how to "integrate with" one. iOS link you provided leads to iOS specific MDM protocol (for example, Google has another MDM philosophy). Thank you for your time anyway, any help is appreciated.